# Objective-c runtime - get property list of NSObject protocol returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsobject, objective-c-runtime

I've been trying to get the list of the properties from the `NSObject` protocol, but I've been having some trouble.

Using the following code to seems to constantly return nil fro the list of properties on that protocol.

```
Protocol *protocol = objc_getProtocol("NSObject");

NSLog(@"%s", protocol_getName(protocol)); // confirms that NSObject protocol is found

unsigned count;

objc_property_t *properties = protocol_copyPropertyList(protocol, &count);

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++) {

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[index])];

    [propertiesArray addObject:key];

}

free(properties);

NSLog(@"%@",propertiesArray); // prints empty array
```

By all accounts this should work. I have even created my own protocol and used it in place of `NSObject` and it works fine.

```
@protocol TestProtocol

@property NSString *someSortOfProperty;

@end
```

The same code as above with only the name of the protocol changed returns the `someSortOfProperty` property.

```
Protocol *protocol = objc_getProtocol("TestProtocol");

NSLog(@"%s", protocol_getName(protocol)); // confirms that TestProtocol protocol is found

unsigned count;

objc_property_t *properties = protocol_copyPropertyList(protocol, &count);

for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++) {

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[index])];

    [propertiesArray addObject:key];

}

free(properties);

NSLog(@"%@",propertiesArray); // prints [85711:303] ( someSortOfProperty )
```

If any of you have succeeded in doing this in the past, or can spot something that I've done wrong that would be great.

Comment: I seriously doubt whether the NSObject "protocol" is implemented as a real protocol, consistent with all the protocol interfaces.  Rather, it's more likely a kluge of code that operates on objects outside of the normal object paradigms.

Comment: [NSObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject) have any properties?

Comment: @BryanChen if you check the source it does, 

`@protocol NSObject
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger hash;

@property (readonly) Class superclass;

...

@property (readonly, copy) NSString *description;
@optional
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *debugDescription;

@end`

Comment: @tecknut but the document doesn't have any. they are just plain methods

Comment: @BryanChen when you get a list of properties for a class that conforms to <NSObject> you get those properties in the list. If they were just plain methods why are they showing up in a property list?

Comment: you are (half)correct, this is what I got: http://pastebin.com/atdzA8p8

Comment: Half correct, the properties are there? @BryanChen are you able to answer my question?

Comment: I tried your code, it print all the properties. so I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce the issue here.  What version of Xcode are you using?